# Does moving in sujood position to fix your position make it invalid?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, prostration

I did two Zuhr prayers because I moved to fix my postition but I don't know if that makes a prayer invalid but I just did another prayer just in case and then I was planning to do a third one but then I broke my prayer because I was confused about my first prayer if its valid or not.

Comment: You are not supposed to move perfectly like a programmed robot.

Comment: Thank you may Allah grant us all Al Jannah Firdaus.